# Split a column into multiple columns based on string pattern (before delimiter)

Tags: r, dataframe, split, grouping

I would like to do the following in R (but am open to suggestions in bash): I have a long list of elements (20,000) that are part of 80 groups. Each group starts with the same string before the underscore delimiter. I want to split the column of all elements into a new data frame containing 80 columns, according to the pattern before the underscore. The columns will have different sizes, so NA values are acceptable.

E.g. the column I want to split:

```
head(df$V1)

FOO1_Yu
FOO1_uN
FOO2_Yo
FOO2_yA
FOO10_nO
FOO10_Yes
FOO1_NoY
```

Desired outcome (a new df, with headers included in the first row):

```
head(df2)
FOO1    FOO2    FOO10
FOO1_Yu FOO2_Yo FOO10_nO
FOO1_uN FOO2_yA FOO10_Yes
FOO1_NoY
```

Any ideas? (And thanks in advance!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses the reshape2 package to get the results you're looking for.  Note that since columns are cast into a long-format data.frame, where missing values exist, they're replaced with NAs (your question shows blank spaces where columns have two vs thee elements, but a true blank isn't possible in a data.frame as all rows need to filled with something, in this case NA where blank).  The approach is as follows:
(1) use str_split to split your name/value pairs by "_" and return these to a data frame
(2) use dcast where the name value is function of your value string

```
library(reshape2)
head(df$V1)

df <- data.frame(V1=c("FOO1_Yu","FOO1_uN","FOO2_Yo","FOO2_yA","FOO10_nO","FOO10_Yes","FOO1_NoY"),stringsAsFactors = F)

splits <- lapply(df$V1,function(x)
  {
    if (!grepl("_",x)) 
    {
      print(paste("Skipping bad input=",x)) 
      return (NULL)
    } else { 
      pair <- unlist(strsplit(x,split="_"))
      name <- pair[1]
      value <- x
      return (data.frame(name=name,value=value)) 
    }
  })

splits <- do.call("rbind",splits)

df <- dcast(splits,value ~ name)
```

The output results as follows:

```
      value     FOO1    FOO2     FOO10
1   FOO1_Yu  FOO1_Yu    <NA>      <NA>
2   FOO1_uN  FOO1_uN    <NA>      <NA>
3   FOO2_Yo     <NA> FOO2_Yo      <NA>
4   FOO2_yA     <NA> FOO2_yA      <NA>
5  FOO10_nO     <NA>    <NA>  FOO10_nO
6 FOO10_Yes     <NA>    <NA> FOO10_Yes
7  FOO1_NoY FOO1_NoY    <NA>      <NA>
```

Comment: Hey Soren, this is perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: With pleasure.  You may also consider replacing above: "value <- x" with "value <- pair[2]" to just get the value-element.  Although the OP suggested need as proposed in the answer.

Comment: Oh, I tried playing with this now because I also needed a table with 1/0s instead of element names and NAs. But then I couldn't really figure out how to adapt your code so I was just cheeky and used `df[!is.na(df)]<-1` and `df[is.na(df)]<-0`.. But your R code really bugged my head - I must improve my R game haha. Thanks a lot!